# What's the correct way to rebase my new version branch?

Tags: git

I have the next version of my code base that I've been working on that's on the `newVersion` branch. I believe what I want to do is rebase `newVersion` with my `master` branch. Basically I'd like to see all the commits on the `newVersion` branch in order, and then the commits on `master` branch. To Illustrate I have two branches:

```
newVersion        master
commitA Jan 1     commitX Jan 2
commitB Jan 2     commitY Jan 3
commitC Jan 3
commitD Jan 4
```

What I want (I think) is to view the commit history as thus:

```
commitD <- newVersion (version 2)
commitC
commitB
commitA
commitY <- master (version 1)
commitX
```

Does this make sense? Is this what I want or do I want something different? What's the git command I want to use  given those branch names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout newVersion
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase master newVersion
```

should do it